# How to prevent image in iframe scrolling on IE 11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

my tested site is here: http://acjs.4fan.cz/test/index.html

It contains 4 identical images of 140 x 140 pixels. The img tag is used for the top row, the iframe tag of 140 x 140 pixels for the bottom row. I'm not going to ask why the display for iframe images is different for different browsers :-)

I am wondering how to prevent the image in iframe scrolling on IE 11, as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jS6FiY8dpUA?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be to set the content to 100% of the interior with CSS and the desired for the iframe in HTML

```
#content{
 width:100%;
height:100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let the image full fill the iframe to prevent it scrolling on IE11. Get the iframe `<body>` and set body's style as `margin:0px;padding:0px` to let it full fill. Here’s the code relating:

```
    <script>
            function a() {
                var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1');
                var b = iframe.contentWindow.document.body;
                b.style.cssText = "margin:0px;padding:0px"; 
            }
    </script>

    <body onload="a()">
        <iframe width="140" height="140" src="image.jpg" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" id="iframe1">
        </iframe>
        <iframe width="140" height="140" src="c1.html" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" id="iframe2">
        </iframe>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you Yu Zhou - it worked. However, now I would like to load the image as src="c1.html", and c1.html contains that loaded image - as shown here: http://acjs.4fan.cz/test-2/index-2.html. Could you please get rid of the vertical scrolling on IE 11?

Comment: I edited my answer above. You should give the iframe with src="c1.html" an id="iframe2", not id="iframe1".

Comment: Thank you for a new version, Yu Zhou. While it is working for src="image.jpg" fine, for some reason it still doesn´t work for src="c1.html", see this video: https://youtu.be/GdWi62MyVH0. Any idea how to fix it on IE 11, please?

Comment: put  `ondragstart="return false;" ` in the `<body>` of c1.html. It disables the scrolling in the iframe.